# Conditional pdf on a Poisson's Binomial Distribution

Tags: binomial-distribution, function, poisson-binomial-distribution

Suppose I have a certain nEV number of Electric Vehicles, each one has a State of Charge (SoC) picked from a particular distribution X.

I have a certain quintic polynomial function g(x) which maps each SoC into a 'probability of positive charging decision' (p_i). Thus, if I'm correct, I have another rv Y=g(X), whose pdf I might calculate.

At each decision instant, the so calculated probability is used to perform nEV Bernouilli trials to determine whether each EV decides to charge or not. As I see it, this decisison (D) is, individually, a Bernouilli, so that D = Be(p_i), and the number of positive decisions (C) is a Poisson's Binomial, so that C = PoB(**p**), being **p** the vector cointaining the probabilities for each EV.

What I want to predict is the total amount of demanded charge. I'm trying to do this by first calculating the mean of the Poisson Binomial and then multiplying it by the mean of the SoCs of those demanding vehicles.

How can I calculate the distribution of SoCs given that a positive charging decision has been taken? What I think I need is f(X|D=1), given that D = Be(Y) and Y=g(X). Maybe this is a triviality, but I'm really stucked and any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that calculation based on bayes rule, but this will require that you know the prior distribution of the SOCs and charging decisions. Let the prior distribution for the SOCs be $h(x)$, then you have

$f(x|D=1)*p(D=1)=f(D=1|x)*h(x)$ which you can solve for the figure of interest.

Comment: Thank you for your answer LiKao. Please, let me further ask whether $f(D=1|x)$ is not directly the pdf of $Y$, as $Y$ gives the probability of a positive charge decision ($D=Be(Y)=1$) given a certain $x$ SoC value.

Comment: @Krugger pdf is usually used to refer to an unconditional distribution, whereas $f(D=1|x)$ is a conditional distribution. However, a conditional distribution is of course also a distribution. Therefore, you are correct $f(D=1|x)$ is the distribution you gave above, it's just not only a pdf, but rather a conditional pdf.

Comment: Ok, that's nice! So, could I assume the following?
1) I can compute the mean $\mu$ of the Poisson Binomial $C$ (that is, the number of expected positive charge decisions for a given vector $\mathbf{p}$ of individual EV charging probabilities).
2) I could obtain the expected aggregated demand directly multiplying this $\mu$ by the mean of $f(D=1|x)*h(x)$.  
3) That aggregated demand ($A=C*X)$) is a compound Poisson process, which pdf I could calculate.